# Vimeo write permission

Tags: oauth, vimeo

In my iOS app i am using Vimeo api, when i tried to add comment to a video it is giving a error saying that the user needs write permission, read permission is granted. 
previously i used the following url for authorization

```
http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize
```

I changed it to

```
http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?permission=write
```

The problem still persists, is the authorization url ok or do i have to give any other parameters. I am using OAConsumer library for OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trail and errors , i got the solution.
instead of specifying permissions=write in the url, we have to give it as a additional parameter using set parameters method of OAMutableRequest.